# Attempt to trigger ASP.NET method by submitting a URL inserts "undefined" parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The following URL triggers a C# ASP.NET method to be run:

`https://example.org/MyController/MyMethod?dateRange=Last%20Month`

And here is the method header:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyMethod(string dateRange)
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I set a breakpoint in the first line of `MyMethod`, I see that the `dateRange` variable is set to "undefined". What am I missing here?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm adding a bit more information. Thanks for your help so far!

Here is the JS function that gets called when a user pressed a button on the UI:

```
function PressButton() {
    var dateRange = $('#date-range-header').val();
    var urlValue = "@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController")" + "?dateRange=" + encodeURIComponent(dateRange);
    alert(urlValue);
    window.open(urlValue, "_self");
}
```

However, it is very weird that the alert displays the following: `/MyController/MyMethod?dateRange=Last%20Month`, which has the correctly encoded "Last Month" value for the `dateRange` variable. Yet within the C# method, `dateRange` equals "undefined".

Comment: inspect and show us request, that triggers this method

Comment: How did you trigger this method? please show your code

Comment: Sounds like you're calling it from javascript and passing an uninitialized variable. "dndefined" is not a .NET thing, and I'm assuming you're seeing it with quotes around it as opposed to something like `null` which would appear without quotes.

Comment: It's weird. :). Did you modify any default codes, such as RouteConfig, FilterConfig, etc ?
Is it possible to provide with git repo link ?

Comment: Can you provide how you pass the string into the controller? I expects you're using AJAX callback like `$.ajax` and the posted data contains `undefined`, so that it converted to string using that value.

Comment: Thank you all. I have added more information - I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[FromQuery]` attribute.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyMethod([FromQuery]string dateRange)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately hasn't worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is for asp.net core